# What are some user-friendly GIS alternatives to Alteryx and ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, analysis, software-recommendations

I'm posting for some inspiration. At my last workplace we used Alteryx extensively for all data analysis, pumping out shapefiles which we'd then symbolise and output maps in ArcGIS.

In my new workplace we don't have Alteryx, and I'm finding it incredibly frustrating to have to do things in Arc which are trivial in Alteryx. For example, join fields from two tables, rename fields, summarise data, filter data, perform field calculations, do spatial operations, drivetimes, intersections etc. ArcGIS is great for making maps, particularly in Python where you can do things in batch. But for analysis and geoprocessing it's just rotten.

So, has anyone else there used Alteryx? Can anyone else feel my pain? And possibly, can anyone suggest any alternatives that I might be able to use? I don't really understand how much Alteryx costs, other than that it'll be an awful lot more expensive than ArcGIS. And boy does it show.

Any suggestions for alternative software from those who might've used both? Thanks

Comment: Which Edition were you using? [Pro?] http://www.alteryx.com/products/compare-editions

Comment: We were using an older version (7) which doesn't equate to the current comparison page. But everything I seek to do with csv, shapefiles and personal geodatabases would be done in the more basic editions

Answer (score 3):

As disclosure, I am SVP Marketing at Alteryx.

Just FYI, we recently lowered prices for the desktop versions and also made them public:

...so you might want to look at most **[recent pricing](http://www.alteryx.com/pricing)** before making a decision, and possibly talk to someone here. Shoot me an email if you want to speak to someone here further about the prices.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  In case you are wondering why your signature was removed - it is because our Help says:

"Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.

Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers. 

Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!"

Comment: Thanks Rick. Could you put your email address on your profile page please so that I can contact you direct? I can't find a way on this site to send a private message, I'm not sure why I can't find that option, but I can't! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are still searching for an alternative to Alteryx - Look into FME, by Safe Software.  Our organization also had problems with Alteryx's pricing.  FME is very similar and much more affordable.

I agree, ESRI is a huge pain when working with tables. FME may or may not be for you. the GUI can take some getting used to if you are accustomed to Alteryx.

Safe Software is pretty generous with their free trials, I'd say give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might like [CARTO](http://carto.com) if you try it out. It seems to have all the capabilities you need, and if you have started using [Alteryx](https://carto.com/connectors/alteryx/) in the meanwhile, we have a great connector so that CARTO can be the visual and interactive output for your alteryx workflows.

Cheers
Miguel
COO at CARTO